# iphone nslog corrupted data

Tags: ios, iphone, nslog, corrupt

I am having a weird problem with variable values. This is the code (it is part of a class method):

```
MyAppDelegate *pDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
SomeDictionaryData *appData = [pDelegate.theData retain];
NSLog(@"my instance var: %@",cardIndex); // outputs "my instance var: 4"
NSDictionary *currentCard = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[appData.cards objectAtIndex:cardIndex]];;
// the above line breaks the app
[currentCard release];
[appData release];
```

I am using the debugger with the `objc_exception_throw` breakpoint. The input received by `objectAtIndex` in there shows as having value = 13760640. The `cards` attribute of appData is an `NSArray` and it clearly does not have ten million + items so I get an out of bounds error. I tried casting with `(int)cardIndex` with no better results. Weird thing is a similar code in some other class works fine.

This is some data I want to use throughout my app so I have a Model class that gets initialized in the AppDelegate as `theData` and then is accesed by different ViewControllers. This error shows up after one successful access on some other ViewController (that one also does retain/release).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[cardIndex unsignedIntValue]` for the `objectAtIndex:` line.

You cannot give `objectAtIndex:` a pointer because it expects an unsigned integer.

For example:

```
NSDictionary *currentCard = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[appData.cards objectAtIndex:[cardIndex unsignedIntValue]]];
```

EDIT:

It sounds like `cardIndex` is an `int` but somewhere along the lines it is being set as an `NSNumber` instance. As a hack, use `[(id)cardIndex unsignedIntValue]`. If this works, then it means you are using the wrong type for `cardIndex` (it should be NSNumber, not `int`).

Comment: Thanks dude! Although I get an "invalid receiver type int" warning.

Comment: Tried casting as (NSUInteger) and still get the warning. Everything else works fine though... I just don't like warnings.

Comment: Right on! Converted all necessary references to NSNumber. Thanks!